# Firebird connection error after converting project from VS2005 to VS2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, connection, firebird

I have a queer problem. I was working on a project with firebird 1.5.6 .NET provider and Visual Studio 2005. Everything worked fine. Then I converted the project to a VS2008 project. Now I have the problem that when I'm trying connecting to firebird database I get the an error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index.
```

The error shows even as I open the connection. I got this error in `server type = Default` but if I set `server type = Embedded` then I have the possiblity to open the connection.

I tried to run my project on an other pc and there it works.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of this error?

Comment: Have you tried the latest 2.5.1 .net provider?
http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider

Comment: @Douglas Tosi. Yes, I'm using 2.5.1 .NET provider.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same error on connect to Interbase.
I fix it.

1. Download Source code NETProvider-2.6.5-src.7z
2. Edit file GdsDatabase.cs
   replace line
   `return this.GetDatabaseInfo(items, IscCodes.BUFFER_SIZE_256)[0].ToString();`

   this

   `ArrayList ar = this.GetDatabaseInfo(items, IscCodes.BUFFER_SIZE_256);
               if (ar.Count > 0)
                   return ar[0].ToString();
               else
                   return String.Empty;`
3. Rebuild project

Done